# SQL variables in query cause unexpected SQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

There is a database that holds music - artists, albums and tracks. Each album has several tracks, each track has it's own track_number inside the album.
I try to execute an SQL request that shifts one track number up (for example, track#4 will be track#3) and at the same time shifts another track number down (ex-track#3 should become track#4). SQL code works perfectly while being run in MySQL Workbench or [SQL sandbox](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvgVidGTHhhxUzx8khPNow/5) but it causes an error while being launched via JDBC.

Replacing IF with standart CASE/WHEN/THEN doesn't help a bit.
Replacing prepared statement with ordinary statement does not do anything good as well.

```sql
SELECT @current_number := track_number, @current_album := album FROM audio_tracks WHERE id = 4;

UPDATE audio_tracks 
    SET track_number = IF(track_number = @current_number - 1, @current_number, @current_number - 1) 
    WHERE @current_number > 1 
        AND track_number IN (@current_number - 1, @current_number) 
        AND album = @current_album;
```

```java
public void processCustomRequest(String sql) throws DaoException
{
    Statement statement = null;
    try
    {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new DaoException("Failed to execute custom SQL request", ex);
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (statement != null)
            {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to close statement", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of expected shifts I got this:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE audio_tracks SET track_number = IF(track_number = @current_number - 1, @c' at line 1`

So... Any ideas how to fix this problem?
Again, here is [the sandbox](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvgVidGTHhhxUzx8khPNow/5) that shows how my table looks and how my request works perfectly. In theory.

Comment: By default you cannot execute multiple statements in a single execute.

Comment: Mark, you are my savior! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the SQL string passed to function and check for the syntax error before execution.

Also use statement.**executeUpdate(sql)** instead of statement.**execute(sql)** function.

Comment: I have tried it already. Unfortunately, what I see looks the very same way it should. I can even copypaste that printed string and use it in sandbox - and get proper results.

Comment: use statement.executeUpdate(sql) instead of statement.execute(sql) function

Comment: Nah, It works fine with usual .execute() method as well.
My problem was I didn't set connection properties correctly.
This little string `properties.put("allowMultiQueries", "true");` made everything work in a proper way.
Thanks for your attempts to help btw!